# Why does this function cast 'const char*' to 'void* const' and not 'const void*'

Tags: c++, templates, casting

This is a very stupid example I came up while working with threads in Windows to wrap a `const_cast` and a `static_cast` into one

```
// Somewhere in the OS API
using function_t = void(*)(void *);
void create_thread(function_t function, void *params);

template <typename T, typename U>
T static_const_cast(U ptr) {
  return const_cast<T>(static_cast<const T>(ptr));
}

void thread_proc(const void* name) {
  // ...
}

void test() {
  const char *name = "name";
  void *params = static_const_cast<void *>(name); // Fails
  // void *params = const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const void *>(name));
  // Succeeds (what I want to achieve with static_const_cast)
  create_thread(reinterpret_cast<function_t>(thread_proc), params);
}
```

but it won't compile on Visual Studio 2017, so I tried gcc and clang on [**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/z/0nIJKW) thinking it should surely be able to compile, but still refuses to with the error message (from gcc 8.2):

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'const char*' to type 'void* const'
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why does it try to cast to `void* const` instead of `const void*` as expected? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Because a constant `void*` is `void * const`, not `const void*`.

Comment: *Why does it try to cast to void\* const instead of const void\** Because you asked it to. T is `void*` and `const T` is `void * const` (**not** `const void*`). By the way avoid `reinterpret_cast` as a plague. Prefer C++ threads facility over the native OS threads API and you won't need any of this.

Comment: @n.m. in that case, it should be able to compile if it's able to compile when the casts are done "separately" instead of my wacky function? Also, this is purely out of curiosity and I'm completely aware of std::thread that makes this mess an ease and avoids all the casting.

Comment: In your separate cast, the target type is `const void *`. This works. In your function, the target type is `void * const`. This doesn't work. I fail to see anything unusual here. Are you wondering why the function has `void * const` instead of `const void *` you wanted, or why `void * const` is wrong?

Comment: _function has void * const instead of const void *_ <-- this. I expected `static_cast<const T>` with T = void* to evaluate to `static_cast<const void *>`

Comment: Think of `*` as a sort of built-in template, `pointer<T>`. You can even write down its definition in terms of `*`: `template<clsss T> using pointer = T*;` Now `const T*` is `pointer<const T*>` and `T * const` is `const pointer<T>`. It's just the weird and misleading syntax of `*` that messes things up. So if you add `const` to any type `A<B>` you will get `const A<B>` not `A<const B>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this function cast 'const char*' to 'void* const' and not 'const void*'

Because you used `void *` as the template argument, and when you apply const to that, it becomes `void * const`. `void *` is a pointer (to non-const object), and making a pointer const results in a const pointer, not a (non-const) pointer to const object.

You could do something like this to achieve what you wanted:

```
return const_cast<T>(
    static_cast<std::remove_pointer_t<T> const*>(ptr)
);
```

However, I recommend instead to use a custom class to wrap the data that you send to the thread. Also, don't cast the function type. Use a function with `void*` argument, and cast the argument within the function.

```
struct params_t {
    const char *name;
};

static params_t params {"name"};

create_thread(thread_proc, &params);
```

No casts needed whatsoever (except obviously in the callback).

Comment: @hermandiedev see my alternative suggestion in the updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes that would be the best course of action. It completely went over my head that applying `const` to a pointer will make the pointer const and not the object pointing to... (facepalm)